# ajax. Retrieve information from query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am really confused at the moment, I am very new to all this just being learning java script and php . I am trying to use ajax to check the db to see if the email exist and then if it is cancel the submit of the form. I cant seem to retrieve the information from the XML. I am probably doing it completely wrong, but that why I am asking here , to lean

So if you could help would be great

**JAVA SCRIPT**

```js
//validate the sign up/regiser form
function validateForm() {

  //Get password varibles 
  var pass = document.forms["signup"]["sign-up-password"].value;
  var confPass = document.forms["signup"]["password-confirm"].value;

  //Check if they match
  if (pass != confPass) {
      alert("Password does not match");
      return false;
  }

  //Ajax functions 
  if(xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4){

    alert("im here");

    email = document.getElementById('email2').value;
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "php/ajaxCom.php?email=" + email, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;

    xmlHttp.send(null);

  }else{
    setTimeout('process()',1000);
  }

}

function handleServerResponse(){
  if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    var check=xmlHttp.status;
    if(xmlHttp.status==200){
      alert("also here 2");
      xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
      xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
      message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

      alert(message);
      return message;
    }
  }
}
```

**php/xml**

```html
<?php
 $status;
 
if (isset($_GET['email'])) {
 $email_in_use = $_GET['email'];

 $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email_in_use."'");

 if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

     $status = false;
 }else{
     if( !mysqli_query( $link, $query ) )
  { $status = mysqli_error( $link ); }
  else
  { $status = true; }
 }

 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?><response><status/></response>');
 $xml->response->status = $status;
 echo $xml->asXML();
 echo $status;
}
?>
```

Comment: Look at this line `mysqli_query( $link, $query )`. `$query` should already be a result object. You also are open to SQL injections with this code, look into prepared statements.

Comment: @chris85 It is a Object it is my query to check the email

Comment: `$query` is not a query though, it is a result object (or false) because you already executed the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are building and handling ajax `XMLHttpRequest` in an incorrect way.
Also, to be able to receive an *XML* response - set additional request header(will be shown further).
Change you ajax request as shown below:

```
   var xmlHttp = null; // this variable should be global to access from different functions
   ...
   //Ajax functions 

    email = document.getElementById('email2').value;

    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "php/ajaxCom.php?email=" + email, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send(null);
...

function handleServerResponse(){  
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      var check=xmlHttp.status;
      var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
      var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
      message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
      alert(message);
      return message;
  } else{
    setTimeout('process()',1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the message is out punting noting

Comment: try to comment this line `echo $status;` to send only xml structure. Also replace this line `xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data` with `xmlDocumentElement.childNodes[0]` and check `message` variable through `console.log(message)`